# Cant display error message in custome form!

Tags: 7

I have create one form which have two fields.

```
$form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Name'),
    '#maxlength' => 20,

    '#required' => TRUE,

);
$form['phone'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Phone'),
    '#maxlength' => 20,
    '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

In page.tpl.php file displayed both fields. Now i have press submit button without enter any value in text box error message will displayed.

But in my page.tpl.php file cant display error message!

How can i show all error message?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you.

In Drupal 7, just add this line in your **custom template** file

```
<?php if ($messages): print $messages; endif; ?>
```

Comment: @user19815 if that is the correct answer, then accept it.